# How to prove that $\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{{\cos((n-1)x)}-{\cos(nx)}}{(1-\cos x)}dx =2\pi$ if $n$ is a positive integer?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to prove that 
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{{\cos((n-1)x)}-{\cos(nx)}}{(1-\cos x)}\,dx =2\pi$$ if $n$ is a positive integer?

I can't prove it from indefinite integration there must be a definite integration rule used here to solve but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, this question must be solvable my coaching teacher marked it as a tough question while giving it as a homewok to us some months ago..

Comment: The integral $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(nx)}{1-\cos x}\,dx$$ is diverging no matter what your coach thinks. However, it is true that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(nx)-\cos((n+1)x)}{1-\cos x}\,dx = 2\pi.$$ Isn't it easier to ask for a proof of that only, without introducing any sequence depending on divergent integrals?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is it ok now?

Comment: Already approved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let we set:

$$ I_n=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_n(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos((n-1)x)-\cos(nx)}{1-\cos x}\,dx$$

[Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition) $$\cos(nx) = 2\cos(x)\cos((n-1)x)-\cos((x-2)x)$$
we have:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2\cos((n-1)x)-2\cos(x)\cos((n-1)x)-\cos((n-1)x)+\cos((n-2)x)}{1-\cos x}\,dx $$
or, simply,
$$ f_n(x)=2-f_{n-1}(x)\implies I_{n} = 4\pi-I_{n-1}.$$
Since it is trivial to check that $I_1=2\pi$, $\,\color{red}{I_n=2\pi}$ follows by induction.

Since $g_n(x)=\frac{1-\cos(nx)}{1-\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin^2\frac{nx}{2}}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}$ can be written as
$$ g_n(x) = f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\ldots+f_n(x),$$
it follows that
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2\frac{nx}{2}}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}\,dx = I_1+I_2+\ldots+I_n = \color{red}{2\pi n}$$
or
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}\right)^2\,dx = \color{red}{\pi n}.$$
(That also follows from the [orthogonality of Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Orthogonality) $U_k$, by the way)

Comment: How can you deduce that $\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2\frac{nx}{2}}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}dx=2n\pi$?

Comment: @ankit: added to my answer.